# Execute JScript when loading Entity from Sitemap

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have a custom entity which has an entry in the sitemap. When I load the entity in the main window, it opens the grid view on the right - standard behaviour so far.

I now want to change some thins in the DOM of the grid body. Therefor I should execute a Javascript while loading the grid. But I have not found any way to do this yet. I sthis possible?

My second way was to but the grid into an Iframe and then do the task on load. This works, but I loose all the buttons from the entity.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best (and probably only) way I can think of to attach [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) to the load of the homepage grid is to add your functionality to a [`CustomRule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309433.aspx) for an `EnableRule` for any object in the custom homepage grid ribbon, which will execute at the time the ribbon loads.

Only caveats: you probably will have to do some validation to make sure the grid is in the right `readyState` before changing anything, and you'll need to make sure to return `true` if you actually want that ribbon object to be enabled.

Comment: This just worked fine. I checked with 
document.getElementById("gridBodyTable").readyState == "complete"
for the state, as the data is in the BodyTable.
My main problem is not solved, but that's another topic. Thank you